# How to sort entries by their descendant count?

Tags: structure, sorting

I want to sort (and paginate) entries from a structure section based on the number of descendants. This is the effective criteria I want to query:

```
craft.entries.section('myStructure').level(1).order('descendants desc')
```

Since `getDescendants.count()` is not a number stored against each entry in the database (AFAIK), how does one go about getting this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Preparse field](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) to calculate and store that value.

The only downside is, it'll only do that calculation when you save the **parent** entry. So if you add another descendant, you'd have to go back and re-save the parent entry to re-calculate the value.

> **Pro tip:** You can go to `Settings > Sections` and re-save the section you are working with. This will automatically trigger a re-save of every single entry in that section.

Comment: I'd like to upvote with half a point for this half baked solution. But as it's probably the only way to approach that problem without custom sql, I'll give you the full upvote. :)

Comment: Lol, thanks @carlcs. It's the only way I could think of without introducing something like template hooks.

Comment: I did come across the Preparse Field plugin while searching for a solution. Since I want this process to be automated, I’m guessing my best bet it to write a custom plugin where I latch on to a hook and trigger a re-save on the parent everytime an entry is modified in that section.

Comment: @rungta: That sounds like a good solution!